# How to kill a Process in Android (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, process, su

In my application I create a process to record a log file extracted from logcat into an Android device. To do this I use a [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html) that just executes `logcat -f log` with `su` permissions and I keep the reference to this process to let the user cancel the log.

The problem is: in my Android version (4.1) I get this exception when I try to call `process.destroy()`

```
I/System  ( 2948): Failed to destroy process 3134
D/dalvikvm( 2221): GC_CONCURRENT freed 499K, 12% free 6962K/7879K, paused 12ms+10ms, total 84ms
I/System  ( 2948): libcore.io.ErrnoException: kill failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/System  ( 2948):  at libcore.io.Posix.kill(Native Method)
I/System  ( 2948):  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.kill(ForwardingOs.java:77)
I/System  ( 2948):  at java.lang.ProcessManager$ProcessImpl.destroy(ProcessManager.java:260)
I/System  ( 2948):  at com.blablabla.android.core.device.debug.DebugDevice.destroyProcess(DebugDevice.java:127)
I/System  ( 2948):  at com.blablabla.android.core.device.debug.DebugDevice.cancelLogcatToFile(DebugDevice.java:98)
```

After checking [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/VcjXWBosQ88), I've modified my cancelLogcatToFile with the suggested solution, so my code is like this:

```
private void exportLogcatToFile(String fileName) {
    String command = new StringBuffer("logcat -f ").append(fileName)
        .append("\n").toString();
    try {
        logcatToFileProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        final DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                logcatToFileProcess.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(command);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

And to kill the process:

```
private void cancelLogcatToFile() {
    if (logcatToFileProcess != null) {
        // logcatToFileProcess.destroy();
        destroyProcess(logcatToFileProcess);
        logcatToFileProcess = null;
        }
    }

private static void destroyProcess(Process process) {
    try {
        if (process != null) {
        // use exitValue() to determine if process is still running.
        process.exitValue();
        }
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
        // process is still running, kill it.
        process.destroy();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:** This code is going to be executed in a rooted device, so `su` will not be a problem.

Also, I know I could do something like `killall logcat` but I want to keep another logcat processes alive

Comment: `su` is not available on most android devices. Is this meant only for rooted devices?

Comment: It's intended for a particular android device which is rooted by default

Comment: Did you try to get the process PID and send a `kill` command?

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the PID from a process created with Runtime.getRuntime().exec().

Comment: Unfortunately java.lang.Process does not seem to expose the underlying native PID.  You could probably figure it out by trolling through /proc/pid looking for candidates as a killall command would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that if you use your hacked `su` shim to launch the process as root, then to literally kill it you will also have to use `su` to launch the `kill` command in order to kill it, as a regular user (such as your application process) cannot kill a process owned by root.

The other possibility would be to see if there is something that would make the process exit on its own.

Comment: I didn't test it yet, but I think you're right, I'll execute this app as system application to see if it works. Meanwhile I'm using "killall logcat" to simplify, thanks for your response!

Comment: A "system app" has nothing to do with root.